# facebook graph api version "2.4 "could not access email,gender information in the "me" tag

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api-v2.4

my sample project at registered at [developer.facebook](http://developer.facebook.com) **version 2.4** and requested permissions are *

> email,birthday,gender

*

**default.aspx**

```
        string code = Request.QueryString["code"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
        {
           // dynamic info = fb.Get("me?birthday");
            string data = FaceBookConnect.Fetch(code, "me");
            FaceBookUser faceBookUser = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<FaceBookUser>(data);
            faceBookUser.PictureUrl = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture", faceBookUser.Id);
            pnlFaceBookUser.Visible = true;
            lblId.Text = faceBookUser.Id;
            lblUserName.Text = faceBookUser.UserName;
           lblName.Text = faceBookUser.Name;
            lblEmail.Text = faceBookUser.Email;
            lblbirthday.Text = faceBookUser.birthday;
            lblf_name.Text =faceBookUser.first_name;
            lblgender.Text = faceBookUser.gender;
           ProfileImage.ImageUrl = faceBookUser.PictureUrl;
            btnLogin.Enabled = false;
        }
```

Comment: And what is the error you are getting? What does fail?

Comment: getting only Id,and Name other feilds are null

Comment: did u find any solution ? i have same issue.

Comment: i will get the solution.